# Abandon leads to invulnerable hero

Tags: dota-2

In a recent game, a player on the opposing team abandoned in the first few minutes. Their hero was WK and he became invulnerable. The WK would follow us and attack, but we couldn't attack him. It was pretty annoying because it eventually ended up in our fountain and would chase us while we were trying to heal. Wouldn't have been too bad but we had 3 quitters on our team so 2 v 4 (plus this crazy WK).

Anything you can do about this? I'm not sure if the other team could or was able to control the WK. We could micro our abandons, but they could also die, unlike the WK.

Comment: You should report this to valve... also... funny as hell :)).

Comment: Did the WK have a refresher and rapier? Because it sounds like he was balling out of control.

Comment: @zozo - Yes, it was funny, annoying too, but funny. Had a team fight at tier 2 mid. Ran back to heal at very low health. Was running in a circle inside the fountain to dodge the WK while healing and buying items. :-o

Comment: Man, you should have gotten this on video!

Comment: I remember in similar game, an abandoned Drow apparently became invulnerable, and Mr.Sniper was complaining all game long and accused us of cheating. I didn't believe it but seeing this Q is changing my mind.

Comment: Yes, I had on game where abandoned razor became invulnerable. It was annoying. Fortunately I was fed enough to destroy the dire fountain before he destroy ours. It was in an autopilot mode.

Comment: Just had a game with Invulnerable Razor. Frustrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were playing limited hero mode (or any mode implying bots), it's a [common known issue](http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=122643) where if a bot has to take over for a leaving player, the hero sometime becomes invincible . There is nothing much you can do about it except dig up an old forum post on [the official website](http://dev.dota2.com/) with your match ID and report the bug once more.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Doesn't sound worth it to report. It was a limited hero game, and no stats were recorded, so no harm. And I did actually enjoy the game, a good challenge to defend 2 v 4. I'd seen invincible abandoned heroes before, just never had one that attacked or chased.

Comment: @ScottO That's because limited heroes mode is the only mode that replaces abandoned players with bots (they don't have AI enough for the full pools of any other mode).

Comment: @ScottO If this happens then all players from the enemy team have control over the hero. When you weren't being attacked it was the enemy playing fair.